# Turn trackpad on/off on MacBook running Windows 8.1 in Bootcamp

Tags: macbook, boot-camp, touchpad

I'm running Windows 8.1 in Bootcamp on a MacBook Pro and I use an external mouse. 
In OSx there is a function that disables the trackpad when a mouse is plugged in, unfortunately this is not the case in Windows 8.1.

How do I quickly enable/disable the trackpad in Windows 8.1? Is there a key combination (SHIFT+F5 ??) or do I have to go through menus?

Comment: Does one of [4 Ways To Quickly Disable The Touchpad in Windows 8](http://windows8themes.org/4-ways-to-quickly-disable-the-touchpad-in-windows-8.html) help?

Comment: Hi David, thanks for the link. Of the four methods, at least three won't work. There is no button on the MacBook (that I know of) that disables the touchpad. I tried to deactivate the apple drivers of input devices, no luck. (Also not my idea of a quick on/off switch). And I can't disable the mouse-button, since I am using an external mouse. The only option left to try is the touchfreeze-program, which I would like to avoid (the more programs running, the slower the system...) I preferably just need a key-combination to turn the touchpad on/off. Or a menu setting. Cheer, Eiril